# Replacement of multiple substrings with re.IGNORECASE

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to replace words in my document with a Python dictionary and I want to realize case insensitive replacements. 
Like we have a string:

```
    string = 'spam fOo bar foo bar spam fOO'
```

and a dictionary:

```
    substitutions = {"foo": "TEST", "bar": "BAR"}
```

in result I want to get:

```
    'spam TEST bar TEST bar spam TEST'
```

i.e. all "foo" words get replaced regadless of capital or small letters.

For this purpose I found the next function:

```
    def replace(string, substitutions):
        regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substitutions)))
        return regex.sub(lambda match: substitutions[match.group(0)], string)
```

it returns me:

```
    'TEST spam fOo BAR TEST BAR spam fOO'
```

i.e. only exact match was replaced. If I put re.IGNORECASE as a flag for re.compile() - nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add re.IGNORECASE and try

```
  ... substitutions[match.group().lower()] ...
```

since subtitutions[match.group()] does not find relevant value when the match is say "fOo"